# Сочетать textImeMultiLine и textMultiLine одновременно

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-style

Мне нужно чтобы текст распределялся в несколько строчек, а точнее две, но в то же время кнопка enter на клавиатуре (самая правая нижняя, может не так назвала) отвечала не за новый абзац, а за функцию далее.
Для первого подходит textMultiLine, для второго - textImeMultiLine.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в Вашем случае можно использовать просто inputType="text"? Остается две строки при android:maxLines="2" и кнопка "enter" заменена на next через android:imeOptions="actionNext".

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:inputType="text"
/>
```